# Every possible combination of logic for tree - Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, math

[image: Example tree]

- The letters represent a true/false value
- True allows the traversal of the lower levels; false means the lower letters will all be false too.
- For example, if **a** is false, all the letters beneath will also be false.
- Given any formation of tree, always with 3 levels, how do I calculate all the valid combinations of true/false values for the all letters?
- Im looking for names of algorithms, links to resources. Not how you would implement it.

Thanks, any help appreciated.

Comment: Depth first and/or breadth-first seem good candidates here

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate all the valid combination of true/false values"? Are you just trying to find out which are true and which are false? Or are you trying to determine something else?

Comment: @KevinWells Im trying to figure out ALL of the possible valid combinations of true and false. For example it would be invalid for j to be true if its parent is false. So one example could be (a=false. b=false, c=false, ... rest are false).

Comment: @zino: You want to find all the possible combinations *for one given forest*? Or you want to find all the possible forests?

Comment: @rici all possible combinations for one given forest.

So the input will be the network of trees. The output will be all valid combinations.

Comment: @zino: OK. I don't have a name for the algorithm, although it is essentially a tree walk, so I gave you pseudocode even though that is not exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple recursive algorithm. The following results in enumerations of sets of letters assigned `T`; since letters are assigned either `T` or `F`, it's obvious how to derive the complete mapping:

```
# I use ++ for the operation of concatenating lists/sets
# and [X] to produce a list/set consisting of the single element X
enumerate(Q, Accum):
  if Q is empty:
    return [Accum]
  else:
    remove the head of Q and put it in Head
    return enumerate(Q, Accum) ++
           enumerate(children(Head) ++ Q, Accum ++ [Head])
```

To enumerate the combinations of a forest, call

```
enumerate(Roots(Forest), [])
```